# How to solve the error when file doesn't exist in setting coordinator ooziee

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, oozie-coordinator

How to solution when error file doesnt exist in setting coordinator oozie:

I have error in log coodinator:

Pig logfile dump:

Backend error message
Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /user/hdfs/jay/part-0.tmp

Setting coordinator:

```
<coordinator-app name="tes-ng" frequency="${coord:minutes(15)}"
start="2015-12-07T10:30+0700" end="2017-02-28T23:00+0700" timezone="Asia/Jakarta"
xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.1" xmlns:sla="uri:oozie:sla:0.1">
<controls>
    <execution>LAST_ONLY</execution>
</controls>
<datasets>
    <dataset name="INPUT_DS" frequency="${coord:minutes(15)}"
        initial-instance="2015-02-16T016:00+0700" timezone="Asia/Jakarta">
        <uri-template>${nameNode}/user/hdfs/jay/${YEAR}/${MONTH}/${DAY}/${HOUR}${MINUTE}
        </uri-template>
        <done-flag></done-flag>
    </dataset>
    <dataset name="OUTPUT_DS" frequency="${coord:minutes(15)}"
        initial-instance="2015-02-16T16:00+0700" timezone="Asia/Jakarta">
        <uri-template>${nameNode}/user/hdfs/jay/output</uri-template>
        <done-flag></done-flag>
    </dataset>
</datasets>
<input-events>
    <data-in name="INPUT" dataset="INPUT_DS">
        <instance>${coord:current(-2)}</instance>
    </data-in>
</input-events>
<output-events>
    <data-out name="OUTPUT" dataset="OUTPUT_DS">
        <instance>${coord:current(-2)}</instance>
    </data-out>
</output-events>
<action>
    <workflow>
        <app-path>${appFolder}</app-path>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>INPUT</name>
                <value>${coord:dataIn('INPUT')}</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>OUTPUT</name>
                <value>${coord:dataOut('OUTPUT')}</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
    </workflow>
</action>
```

What I want is when I get error File does not exist, oozie can hold until file is all ready. any idea..??

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve the error when file doesn't exist in setting coordinator oozie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34310152/how-to-solve-the-error-when-file-doesnt-exist-in-setting-coordinator-oozie)

Comment: This is exact duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34310152/how-to-solve-the-error-when-file-doesnt-exist-in-setting-coordinator-oozie and also filed by the same author